# "when is he expected back" Vs " what time is he expected back"

Tags: grammar

Are these questions correct and how can we answer these questions correctly.Could anyone help me out,please?I always get confusion while asking and answering these questions.Please need your valuable suggestions!Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*When* is less specific. The answer could be, depending on the context known to the speakers, for example, *at six o'clock, tomorrow, next month,* etc. "What time ...? expects the answer to be a time, for example, "at six o'clock".

Comment: Is it correct to say like he is expected to be around one or two hours later or he is expected around at 4 o'clock.Thanks